# Assignment to leftBarButtonItem has no effect after first time

Tags: ios, ios8, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I am setting up an "Edit" / "Done" button as follows:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

This works the first time around (from within `viewWillAppear:`) but not on subsequent occasions (after an `UISegmentedControl` changed its value) and after having set `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` to `nil` in between. I have confirmed that all such assignments occur on the main thread.

Am I supposed to explicitly force an update of the navigation bar in the UI (with an equivalent of `setNeedsDisplay`) or what else could go wrong here?

Comment: where do you assign this?  I mean in which view delegate?

Comment: In a `UITableViewController` that acts as `UITableViewDelegate` of its own `tableView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this call instead resolves the issue, although I am not yet sure how.

```
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem: self.editButtonItem animated: YES];
```

I'd still appreciate an answer as to how.

Answer (score 0):

navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true

did it for me